# Listbox does not display values of a specific object (Databinding)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, itemssource

I want the ListBox called LstbClients to show Name and Phonenumber in each Label or TextBlock (it does not matter to me), I have DataBinded before with a ComboBox and that worked pretty well, but for some reason it's not working for this ListBox.

This is the XAML code.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstbClients"
         Height="300"
         Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
         Style="{StaticResource inputControls}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding clients}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Label Content=", "/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Phonenumber}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is the code behind:

```
//clients is a filled ObservableCollection<client>
lstbClients.ItemsSource = clients;
```

This is the code behind Client.cs

```
public class Client
{
    public int ID;
    public string Lastname;
    public string Name;
    public string Streetname;
    public string Postcode;
    public string City;
    public int Phonenumber;
    public string Email;
    public DateTime CreationDate;
    public DateTime BirthDate;

    public Client(int id, string lastname, string name, DateTime birthDate, string streetname, string postcode, string city, int phonenumber, string email, DateTime creationDate)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Lastname = lastname;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Streetname = streetname;
        this.Postcode = postcode;
        this.City = city;
        this.Phonenumber = phonenumber;
        this.Email = email;
        this.CreationDate = creationDate;
        this.BirthDate = birthDate;
    }
}
```

For some odd reason the Labels of the ListBox does only show the "," and ignores the Name and Phonenumber, and yes when I "open" ListBox with my final WPF application, all the data does contain... So the ListBox get's the Data but it just doesn't want to display it on the label of the lstbClients, so I cannot identify which label contain what data.

Comment: Show code for client class. And why are you setting ItemsSource from XAML and from code behind?

Comment: Welcome to the site! There's no need to add the "excuse me, I'm a beginner" to your question - everyone has been a beginner, so don't worry about it. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Your XAML looks fine, I am guessing you have not implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your Observable Collection. Please show code for declaration of Observable Collection. Also, check your output window during run-time to assure you are not getting Binding Errors. Those can help you find your problem.

Comment: I indeed don't have INotifyPropertyChanged... isn't that something for MVVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Binding works with properties and not with fields.

Change your fields to properties like this:

```
public string Name {get; set;}
public int Phonenumber {get; set;}
```

On a sidenote you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your class in case you want GUI to be refresh on any property change. Refer to this for reference - [How to implement Property change notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! This works, I always though that get and set aren't necessary when you don't put logic within it... but it looks like I'm wrong. Anyway, thank for this answer, I will also look more about INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: These are automatic properties. Compiler will automatically create backup fields for you behind the scenes.